# Splitting django project in two big modules and getting import problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I want to start a new enterprise project which will be very large and will have thorough business logic. I want to split it into two "sub-projects", one with the models, API, and business logic (called "business"), and the other with the views for the web app (called "webapp").

The idea of separating the web app (views) from the models, API, and business logic is because I want these 3 lasts to be the service for both web app and mobile too, and the business logic is very detailed, hence I needed a dedicated project to handle it.

The layout looks like this:

```
project/
 + business/
 |  + __init__.py
 |  + rest_urls.py
 |  + business_app_1/
 |  |  + __init__.py
 |  |  + controllers.py
 |  |  + models.py
 |  |  + serializers.py
 |  + business_app_2/
 |  |  + __init__.py
 |  |  + controllers.py
 |  |  + models.py
 |  |  + serializers.py
 + project/ #this one is just the main configuration django app
 |  + __init__.py
 |  + settings.py
 |  + urls.py
 |  + wsgi.py
 + webapp/
 |  + __init__.py
 |  + urls.py
 |  + view_app_1/
 |  |  +  views.py
 |  + view_app_2/
 |  |  + views.py
 |  + view_app_n/
 |  |  + views.py
```

I just ran a test because I never made a complex layout like this, and I got an import error (`ModuleNotFoundError`)

view_app_1/views.py:

```
from business.business_app_1.models import BusinessModel1
print(BusinessModel1())
```

I just tried to run it from the terminal and it says that there is no module named 'business' (all of my folders have an **init**.py except by root, although I tried adding it there too).

Is there any way to import this without `sys` module hacks?

Comment: Your `PYTHONPATH` does not include your project root. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path . Alternatively, create a `.env` file in your project root and set it there.

Comment: BTW, your approach to defining the apps within the project, given this is a *large* enterprise app, is a bad one. I suggest you read up on DDD and how to manage service boundaries for a service based architecture. You are building for future problems with the current approach.